# The dynamic value of the field, depending on the authorized user

Tags: feeds

Friends, hello. I ask for help, I can’t figure it out. I have the following task: There is a node type "product", it has a field "field_product_url". A link is imported into this field using the Feeds module. The link is usually of the form ad.admitad.com/blabla/blabla/subid1=userid. I need that after the user logs in, userid changes to the id of the user who logged into the site. For example, for a user with uid 2, the link should be like this: ad.admitad.com/blabla/blabla/subid1=2. That is, the value of this field must be dynamic, and change for each user. I was advised by hook_node_view, but I still did not understand how to do this. Please advise how I can solve this problem. I will be grateful).

Comment: If the field supports tokens, use the current user user id in place of that literal value.

Comment: Hi Nikolasun, welcome to drupal.stackexchange.com. what is your drupal version?